# Set a "type" to pushpin using the Bing Theme

Tags: maps, bing-maps, pushpin

i m using the last version of bing maps with the bing theme module, i wanted to add a class name to hide it via css, i think this is done using the typeName property, but with the bing theme it doesn't work. that property is used to set the micro pushpin style. Is there a better way?

also what's the best way to in the same way have diffrent group types of pushpins so i can hide/show group of pins in the map. Should i use multiple entity layers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm it is unfortunate that they broke the `typeName` feature with the bing themes module.

I wonder why you need CSS to hide the pushpins though.  There is a Boolean pushpin option called `visible` that you can toggle, is there a reason why you are not using it?
If you have to use css, the micro pushpins in bing themes module seem to have a class of `pin0`.  So you can add the following style to your page to hide all of them(then use jquery to modify the style later to unhide):

```
<style>
.pin0 {
    display:none
}
</style>
```

> "also what's the best way to in the same way have diffrent group types
>   of pushpins so i can hide/show group of pins in the map. **Should i use
>   multiple entity layers**?"

Yes

Comment: I wanted to style the pins with css, and use css animations on them (hide/show), also i wanted to use diffrent css class for difrent types.